# 404 on assets folder with Cypress Component Testing

Tags: angular, typescript, cypress, assets, cypress-component-testing

I do my first component testing with Cypress within an Angular environment and I have problems to render styles and scripts from nodes_modules and assets folder when testing. I would require helps to make it works successfully.

The guide https://docs.cypress.io/guides/component-testing/angular/overview says I can use the options API to provide my own project specific configuration to the devServer. The devServer configuration receives an options property. So in my understanding, I should use the options API. Start from there, here is my config :

```
component: {
        devServer: {
            framework: 'angular',
            bundler: 'webpack',
            options: {
                projectConfig: {
          root: '',
          sourceRoot: 'src',
          buildOptions: {
                        outputPath: "dist",
                        index: "index.html",
                        main: "main.ts",
                        polyfills: "src/polyfills.ts",
                        tsConfig: "tsconfig.app.json",
            inlineStyleLanguage: 'scss',
            assets: [
                            "src/favicon.ico",
                            "src/assets",
                        ],
                        styles: [
                            "node_modules/@angular/material/_theming.scss",
                            "node_modules/.../scss/material-theme/3-generic/_base.scss",
                            "node_modules/.../scss/material-theme/3-generic/_fonts.scss",
                            "node_modules/.../scss/material-theme/main.scss",
                            "src/styles.scss"
                        ],
            scripts: [],
            buildOptimizer: false,
            optimization: false,
            vendorChunk: true,
            extractLicenses: false,
            sourceMap: true,
            namedChunks: true,
          },
        },
      },
        },
        specPattern: '**/*.cy.ts',
    },
```

Then, I did create component.index.html with basic template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Components App</title>
    <base href="/" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-cy-root></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then, I did add in component.ts

```
declare global {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-namespace
    namespace Cypress {
        interface Chainable {
            mount: typeof mount;
        }
    }
}

Cypress.Commands.add(
  'mount',
  (component: Type<unknown> | string, config: MountConfig<T>) => {
    return mount(component, {
      ...config,
      autoSpyOutputs: true,
    })
  }
)
```

But, when tests are executing, labels and images don't show and give this sort of error

> ```
> (uncaught exception)HttpErrorResponse: Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/assets/i18n/fr.json: 404 Not Found. 
> (uncaught exception)HttpErrorResponse: Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/assets/img/sun.jpg: 404 Not Found
> ```

If you know how to help, help me thanks

Samantha
[1]: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/component-testing/angular/overview